# Randomize stylesheet.css per page visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random

I have a quick question what the best practice approach is with JS or Jquery concerning the randomization of stylesheets.

I plan to 5 to 6 different stylesheet.css documents handling only color elements (background, href, color). What I try to achieve is to randomize which stylesheet file (For example red, green, black, white) is loaded per user visit.

Is there a JS library for this purpose or a common practice in use already?

Comment: group css by top level class name like `red` then add that to body. Changing that on load to random color should change everything

Comment: StackOverflow isn't so much about recommendations, as it is "I have x code that doesn't do Y functionality. Can someone help me solve this specific problem".

If you post an example of something you have tried already - the community may be able to better assist you.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex and Cerlin!

Comment: If all you want to change are some colors I think it is better to use one stylesheet and use CSS variables that you change via javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
const stylesheets = ["main1.css","main2.css","main3.css","main4.css"];

let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);

document.head.appendChild('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + stylesheets[random] + '">');
```

Comment: Thank you Dogukan! I will try that

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4ojqafce/4/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div width="100px" height="100px" class = "innerview">

    </div>
</body>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const colors = ["red","yellow","green","blue"];

    var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
    $("body").removeClass()
    $("body").addClass(colors[index])
})
```

**CSS**

```
.innerview {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.red .innerview {
    background-color: red;
}

.yellow .innerview {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.green .innerview {
    background-color: green;
}

.blue .innerview {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Loading different css will be a overkill for this simple problem i guess